# Read Excel in windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, io

is there any free tool to read excel without using Excel Interop. I am creating a website using Visual studio 2010, and I am using c# and asp. I cant install any software on server so I want to use some third party free tool. I read the file and have to use the contents to update the db,. I want to read Both XLSX and XLS Need some suggestions for that. Thanks

Comment: Define "read Excel."  If you're just pulling data, linqtoexcel might work: http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: I read the file and have to use the contents to update the db,. I want to read Both  XLSX and XLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADO.NET to read from an Excel File which enables you to  use a spreadsheet as you would a table in a database.

Here's the sample connection string that uses the JET OLEDB Provider from [connectionstrings.com/excel](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
       Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
       Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Comment: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. Error : do I have to install any software in my server

Answer (score 2):

I used ExcelDataReader on a recent project, worked great for reading the XLS/XLSX files.

[Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

BTW: [Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).